# Como creo tablas en MySql a través de Xammp?

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, tablas

Necesito crear las tablas a traves de una consulta con este codigo, y me tira error continuamente, y no se si es que estoy haciendo algo mal o es otra cosa... antiguamente utilice el codigo para sql server de microsoft y anduvo perfecto

```
use guarderias

CREATE TABLE guarderias(
    precioBaseDia int NOT NULL,  
    precioBaseMes int NOT NULL ,
    precioBaseAño int NOT NULL,
    precioMensual float NOT NULL ,
    tipoVehiculo varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    codigo int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (codigo)
) 
CREATE TABLE clientes(
    dni int NOT NULL,  
    nombre varchar(45) NOT NULL ,
    apellido varchar(45) NOT NULL ,
    telefono int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dnI),

)
 CREATE TABLE empleados(
    dni int NOT NULL,
    codEmpleado int NOT NULL,  
    nombre varchar(45) NOT NULL ,
    apellido varchar(45) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (dni ),

) 

 CREATE TABLE vehiculos(
    dueño int NOT NULL,  
    cilindrada int NOT NULL ,
    modelo varchar(45) NOT NULL ,
    marca varchar(45) NOT NULL ,
    patente varchar(10) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (patente ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_dueño FOREIGN KEY (dueño)REFERENCES clientes( dni)

) 

CREATE TABLE  recibosTaller(
        fecha date NOT NULL,
        cliente int NOT NULL,
        numero int NOT NULL,
    codEmpleado int NOT NULL,  
    descripcion varchar(256) NOT NULL ,
    total float NOT NULL ,
    codigo int NOT NULL ,   
    PRIMARY KEY (numero),
    CONSTRAINT FK_emple FOREIGN KEY ( codEmpleado)REFERENCES empleados( codEmpleado),
    CONSTRAINT FK_clien FOREIGN KEY (cliente)REFERENCES clientes( dni)
) 

CREATE TABLE  recibosGuarderia(
        fecha date NOT NULL,
        cliente int NOT NULL,
        numero int NOT NULL,
    patente varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
    total float NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (numero),
    CONSTRAINT FK_vehic FOREIGN KEY ( patente)REFERENCES vehiculos( patente),
    CONSTRAINT FK_client FOREIGN KEY (cliente)REFERENCES clientes( dni)
)
```

Comment: ¿y cuál es el error que te da?

Comment: De primeras faltan los `;` en las sentencias. Aparte ¿que tiene que ver esto con Java?

Answer (score 2):

Edit 17/07/2019:

Hay varios errores en las sentencias, es improbable que funcionase anteriormente:

- Nunca puede haber comas antes del paréntesis de cierre del CREATE TABLE
- Había una mayúscula sobrante en la declaración de dni como PRIMARY KEY en la tabla clientes
- Al crear FOREIGN KEYs dentro de los CREATE TABLE no es necesario poner ADD CONSTRAINT. Sólo se usa cuando añades la KEY con un ALTER TABLE.
- Para poder marcar una columna como FOREIGN KEY ésta debe ser PRIMARY KEY o INDEX a su vez.

Además:

- Había espacios sobrantes dentro de las sentencias, probablemente mysql se quejaría también de ello
- Siempre que puedas evita el uso de caracteres no internacionales como la 'ñ', incluso si el set de caracteres de la BD es utf8 u otro internacional. Te ahorrará muchos posibles errores.

Aquí tienes la sentencia bien formateada:

```
CREATE TABLE guarderias(
precioBaseDia INT NOT NULL,
precioBaseMes INT NOT NULL,
precioBaseAno INT NOT NULL,
precioMensual FLOAT NOT NULL,
tipoVehiculo VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
codigo INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE clientes(
    dni INT NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    apellido VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    telefono INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(dni)
);

CREATE TABLE empleados(
    dni INT NOT NULL,
    codEmpleado INT NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    apellido VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(dni),
    KEY(codEmpleado)
);

CREATE TABLE vehiculos(
    dueno INT NOT NULL,
    cilindrada INT NOT NULL,
    modelo VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    marca VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    patente VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(patente),
    FOREIGN KEY(dueno) REFERENCES clientes(dni)
);

CREATE TABLE recibosTaller(
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    cliente INT NOT NULL,
    numero INT NOT NULL,
    codEmpleado INT NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    total FLOAT NOT NULL,
    codigo INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(numero),
    FOREIGN KEY(codEmpleado) REFERENCES empleados(codEmpleado),
    FOREIGN KEY(cliente) REFERENCES clientes(dni)
);

CREATE TABLE recibosGuarderia(
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    cliente INT NOT NULL,
    numero INT NOT NULL,
    patente VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    total FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(numero),
    FOREIGN KEY(patente) REFERENCES vehiculos(patente),
    FOREIGN KEY(cliente) REFERENCES clientes(dni)
);
```

SQL es bastante delicadito con el formato, te recomiendo fijarte bien en ese tipo de detalles.
Un formateador como el del phpMyAdmin de XAMPP puede ayudarte, aunque los hay mejores.

Échale un ojo a la documentación de mysql, es bastante buena: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html

---

Original:
No creo que estas comas antes de cerrar paréntesis le gusten a la BD, y dudo muchísimo que funcionasen antes en ningún sitio.

```
PRIMARY KEY (dnI),

)
```

- Además veo un montón de espacios sobrantes entre paréntesis
- Mayúsculas que sospecho que no deben estar ahí
- Y errores de ese estilo que deberías revisar.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/165627)

Comment: Gracias por la revisión, Aprendiz.

Jheyman: Como dices, mi respuesta era más apropiada para un comentario, pero no puedo comentar y no podía dar una respuesta más extensa en el momento. Intentaré conectarme esta tarde y dar una respuesta más elaborada.

Debería darle la solución completa a Daniel? La query funcionando, en este caso?

Ah, y no entiendo por qué me han dado puntos de reputación, dado que las 3 recomendaciones respecto a la respuesta son eliminarla. Gracias!

Comment: Buenas Jose R. Gracias por responder y agradeceriamos que la editaras para añadir más informacion cuando puedas. Te han dado puntos porque tienes 1 upvote y 1 downvote. Un saludo!